# Why my Activity which using a custom layout cant show?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using Android Studio write a program for studying and I defined a custom layout extends Relativelayout like follow:

```
public class ClipLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    private Path clipPath;
    private int centerX, centerY;
    private float clipRadius;
    private int clipHeight;
    private String clipColor;
    private boolean duringAnim;
public ClipLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public ClipLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public ClipLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

public ClipLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init();
}
private void init() {
    clipPath = new Path();
    clipColor = "#ffffff";
    duringAnim = false;
    setWillNotDraw(false);
}}
```

I crate a sample Activity in Android Studio,at beginning it worked.but after I use it in XML of the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<matsui.cfc.cqut.com.oritsuru.ClipLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/house_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ><!--tools:context="matsui.cfc.cqut.com.oritsuru.HouseActivity"-->
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_coll_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/head"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.8"/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/house_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_house" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</matsui.cfc.cqut.com.oritsuru.ClipLayout>
```

the screen show anything but blank.I can click button on toolbar of some component such as the floatingactionbutton. what should I do?

append:i m sorry i missed init(), and the screen show nothing, just white.(i dont know how to use this clearly, so i dont know how to reply you...)

Comment: post init() method also

Comment: rebuild the project it will show after that

Comment: How does your activity look like?